# Curl Get/Post command line script

Tags: php, curl, post, get, server

Good evening,

I am currently in a position where I need to use a VPN in order to access the internet. I have found a server I like very much as it is free and the latency is low for me. The server signup page is hosted at https://www.tcpvpn.com/create-udpvpn-account-server. The problem is that every 5 days I have to recreate an account to access the server as per their policy. I've used curl in my classes before and was trying to make it so I can automate the process of creating a new account.

So, I execute the command:

```
curl https://www.tcpvpn.com/create-udpvpn-account-server >> output.txt
```

This gives me the file with the following output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="Lg1B1tLlSQ5j5hU0msAnyw5dxaMngUScJBzt2UwS6Tw"/>
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="Kuieqxus41e0tinyQB04icm10gTbH4x1hgkWcV6cRDg"/>
<meta name="msvalidate.01" content="E37DD70D48269B029B682E6C51997991"/>
<meta name="alexaVerifyID" content="_d7toKLPOA4toMKiOgJrg9QLwo0"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
try{if (!window.CloudFlare) {var CloudFlare=[{verbose:0,p:0,byc:0,owlid:"cf",bag2:1,mirage2:0,oracle:0,paths:{cloudflare:"/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=1613a3a185/"},atok:"f1285dc6b240c6d921956394f9443f98",petok:"fc6cb71e1d3370d5423bdad256a7b050cf9a8798-1474908509-1800",zone:"tcpvpn.com",rocket:"0",apps:{"ga_key":{"ua":"UA-65041386-1","ga_bs":"2"}},sha2test:0}];!function(a,b){a=document.createElement("script"),b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],a.async=!0,a.src="//ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=0489c402f5/cloudflare.min.js",b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)}()}}catch(e){};
//]]>
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/site.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/pygments.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.css">
<link href="navbar-static-top.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/css/metro-bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/docs.css">
<link href="css/flag-icon.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="navbar-static-top.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="foto/tcpvpnfv.png"/>
<link rel="alternate" href="http://tcpvpn.com/" hreflang="x-default"/>
<script src="js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
<script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>

<meta content='ID Google Webmaster Verfikasi' name='google-site-verification'/>
<meta content='ID Bing Verification' name='msvalidate.01'/>
<meta content='ID Alexa Verification' name='alexaVerifyID'/>
<link rel="profile" href="http://tcpvpn.com/sitemap/sitemap.xml"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://31804627.ranking.fc2.com/analyze.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<title>Create Free OpenVPN UDP Account | TcpVPN.com</title>
<meta charset='utf-8'/>
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1' name='viewport'/>
<meta content='http://www.TcpVPN.com' property='og:url'/>
<meta content='Udp Vpn Account' property='og:site_name'/>
<meta content='Server Udp VPN Account' property='og:title'/>
<meta content='website' property='og:type'/>
<meta property='fb:app_id' content='983032945042669'/>
<meta property='fb:admins' content='kzs.oftz'/>
<meta name='description' content='create account vpn '/>
<meta name='keywords' content='create account vpn '/>
<meta name='author' content='TcpVPN.com'/>
<meta name='rating' content='general'/>
<meta name='distribution' content='global'/>
<meta name='copyright' content='TcpVPN.com'/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (top.location != self.location) {
      top.location = self.location
    }
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-65041386-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

(function(b){(function(a){"__CF"in b&&"DJS"in b.__CF?b.__CF.DJS.push(a):"addEventListener"in b?b.addEventListener("load",a,!1):b.attachEvent("onload",a)})(function(){"FB"in b&&"Event"in FB&&"subscribe"in FB.Event&&(FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create",function(a){_gaq.push(["_trackSocial","facebook","like",a])}),FB.Event.subscribe("edge.remove",function(a){_gaq.push(["_trackSocial","facebook","unlike",a])}),FB.Event.subscribe("message.send",function(a){_gaq.push(["_trackSocial","facebook","send",a])}));"twttr"in b&&"events"in twttr&&"bind"in twttr.events&&twttr.events.bind("tweet",function(a){if(a){var b;if(a.target&&a.target.nodeName=="IFRAME")a:{if(a=a.target.src){a=a.split("#")[0].match(/[^?=&]+=([^&]*)?/g);b=0;for(var c;c=a[b];++b)if(c.indexOf("url")===0){b=unescape(c.split("=")[1]);break a}}b=void 0}_gaq.push(["_trackSocial","twitter","tweet",b])}})})})(window);
/* ]]> */
</script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">#blockblockA{position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;background-color:#000000;width:100%;height:100%;}#blockblockA td{text-align:center;width:100%;height:100%;}#blockblockA td p{font:bold 15px Verdana;color:#ffffff;}#blockblockA td div{font:bold 13px Verdana;color:#ffffff;}#blockblockB{visibility:invisible;display:none;}#linkA{font:bold 12px Verdana;color:#ffffff;}</style>
<noscript>
<style type="text/css">#blockblockA{visibility:invisible!important;display:none!important;}#blockblockA td{visibility:invisible!important;display:none!important;}#blockblockA td p{visibility:invisible!important;display:none!important;}#blockblockB{visibility:visible!important;display:block!important;}</style>
</noscript>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ads/advertisement.js"></script>
<table id="blockblockA"><tr><td>
<p>Please Disable Adblock To View This Website</p>
</td></tr></table>
<span id="blockblockB"/> <body>

<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-NHWMX8');</script>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
MENU
</button>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class=""><a href="https://www.tcpvpn.com/home" title="free vpn server Accounts"> <i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home </a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> VPN Server <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li class=""><a href="https://www.tcpvpn.com/Free-VPN" title="Free TCP VPN server Accounts">VPN TCP Server</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="https://www.tcpvpn.com/Free-VPN" title="Free UDP VPN server Accounts">VPN UDP Server</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="https://www.tcpvpn.com/vpn-torrenting" title="vpn support torrent">VPN Torrenting</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="https://www.tcpvpn.com/check-vpn-account" title="check vpn account">Check VPN Account</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="https://www.tcpvpn.com/generate-IP-Address-to-IP-Decimal" title="generate ip to decimal">Generate IP to Decimal</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class=""><a href="https://www.tcpvpn.com/free-vpn-sgdo-server" title="free vpn sgdo server">X-SGDO</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">PPTP<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li class=""><a href="https://www.tcpvpn.com/free-vpn-server-protocol-pptp" title="Free VPN Server Protocol PPTP">PPTP Server</a></li>
<li><a target=\'blank\' href="http://mytunnel.info/openvpn/how-to-connect-pptp-in-tcpvpn-com/" title="how to connect PPTP VPN">How To Connect</a></li>              
              </ul>
        </li>
            <li class=""><a href="https://www.tcpvpn.com/exclusive-server" title="exclusive openvpn">EXC Server</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="https://www.tcpvpn.com/download-software-open-vpn" title="download software openvpn client android, ios, windows">Download Software</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Server Config<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li class=""><a href="https://www.tcpvpn.com/tcp-vpn-config" title="openvpn config tcp server">TCP Server</a></li>              
                <li class=""><a href="https://www.tcpvpn.com/udp-vpn-config" title="openvpn config udp server">UDP Server</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="https://www.tcpvpn.com/tcp-vpn-sgdo-config" title="openvpn config sgdo server">SGDO Server</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="https://www.tcpvpn.com/tcp-vpn-sggs-config" title="openvpn config sggs server">TCP SGGS Server</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="https://www.tcpvpn.com/exclusive-vpn-config" title="openvpn config exclusive server">Exclusive Server</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>           
            <li class=""><a href="https://www.tcpvpn.com/squid-proxy" title="squid proxy">Squid Proxy</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="https://www.tcpvpn.com/dns-records" title="dns server and generate config">DNS</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="https://www.tcpvpn.com/request-and-report" title="request and report tcpvpn.com">Report</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="https://www.tcpvpn.com/terms-of-service" title="terms of service">TOS</a></li>            

            <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Follow Us <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

            <li><a target=\'blank\' href='https://www.facebook.com/pages/Tcpvpn/983032945042669' title='fanpage tcpvpn.com'><i class='fa fa-facebook'></i> FB Fan Page</a></li>
                <li><a target=\'blank\' href='https://www.facebook.com/groups/540972616005468/' title='fb groub tcpvpn.com'><i class='fa fa-users'></i> FB Group</a></li>
            <li><a target=\'blank\' href='https://twitter.com/tcp_vpn' title='twitter tcpvpn.com'><i class='fa fa-twitter'></i> Twitter</a></li>              </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>




        <div class="header">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-2"> 
                <div class="lgtcp">
                <img src='foto/tcpvpn.png' width='150px;' alt='logo-tcpvpn.com' title='logo tcpvpn.com'>                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="hdinfo">
                <span class="label label-success"><i class="fa fa-wifi"></i> IP Active : 139.59.144.231 </span>


                <span class="label label-success"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Server Time : 23:48:28 26/09/2016  </span>


                <span class="label label-success"><i class="fa fa-history"></i>  Reset : 00:01 ( GMT+7) </span>


                <span class='label label-success'><a href='https://www.tcpvpn.com/login-point' title='login fitur point in tcpvpn.com'><i class='fa fa-angle-double-down'></i> Fitur Point (Account 1 Month)</a></span>                 
            </div>      
        </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="openvpnbody">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php'>
```

I've tried to read through the cURL manual to figure out what I'm looking for to send the proper command. I figure I can use POST or GET, but I'm not sure past that where in this code I'm supposed to look to know what command to say. In the examples on the manual, it has POST and GET shown in the code, however my code does not have that anywhere. Stackoverflow recommends the PHP tag, but I am not familiar with what PHP is and don't know if this falls in this category. If it does not, is there a method of using that to do what I'm asking that may be easier? Any guidance in this part would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you should be able to post values for fields "username" and "password" to the URL. I'm not sure the response, you'll have to play with that. Try reading the PHP manual for cURL. I've linked the page for setting options, and would recommend you pay attention to example 2. http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Those examples look really similar to my curl code I've done before, but mine was done in C. Even knowing what that code is doing though, I don't see how it can help me without knowing how I'm supposed to send the response. I tried adding -u test:testpassword to my command, and it outputs the exact same text. I'll keep looking for a clue.